# Override colour for gradient setting in Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm making a new website which is under development:
https://wowwdigital.wpengine.com

I'm using a Wordpress theme called Salient which uses colours set from the theme settings:
http://themenectar.com/docs/salient/theme-options/accent-colors/

There is a specific element called "fancy box" which has a variable for colour, but instead of input of hex codes, it has a dropdown for the 6 accent colours.

I want to use the gradient options, but I want more than two.

Unlike other normal elements where one can find the class and override the existing class this has something which I haven't seen before

```
data-color="extra-color-gradient-2"
```

Now I don't quite understand what this means. I'd really appreciate some guidance on how I could override the CSS to add in gradient colours for the fancy boxes.

I appreciate any tips, so thanks in advance!

[image]

```
<div class="nectar-fancy-box  " data-style="color_box_hover" data-animation="" data-box-color-opacity="1" data-delay="" data-alignment="left" data-color="extra-color-gradient-2"><div class="box-inner-wrap"><div class="box-bg"></div> <div class="inner" style="min-height: 200px"><div class="inner-wrap"><i class="icon-default-style iconsmind-Code-Window" data-color="extra-color-gradient-2" style="font-size: 50px!important; line-height: 50px!important;"></i><i class="icon-default-style hover-only iconsmind-Code-Window" data-color="white" style="font-size: 50px!important; line-height: 50px!important;"></i>
```

#### Website Design

Professionally built WordPress websites that are fast, mobile friendly and stunning to look at.

[image]

Comment: there is some JS behind this, these data are used with some function in order to achive things

Comment: Is the attribute 'data-color' in your code or do you see it on the div only after the page loads?

Comment: The data color is something I see from inspection with chrome after the page loads.

Comment: Added a screenshot now with the settings page.